# d3.stack in AngularJs2

Tags: angularjs, angular, d3.js

I am trying to draw a stack bar chart ([like this code](https://bl.ocks.org/DimsumPanda/689368252f55179e12185e13c5ed1fee)) using d3, in a Angularjs2 component. The following line works in Javascript:

```
var datasample="ethnicity,F Under 25,F Over 75,F 25 to 50,F 50 to 75,M Under 25,M Over 75,M 25 to 50,M 50 to 75\n"+
          "Asian,327,296,332,309,306,330,307,323\n"+
          "Black,294,302,330,305,295,363,322,292";
          var data= this.d3.csvParse(datasample);
          g.selectAll(".serie")
            .data(d3.stack().keys(data.columns.slice(1))(data))
```

However, I get the following error, when I use it in typescript inside the component.

```
Argument of type 'DSVParsedArray<DSVRowString>' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ [key: string]: number; }[]'.
  Types of property 'includes' are incompatible.
    Type '(searchElement: DSVRowString, fromIndex?: number) => boolean' is not assignable to type '(searchElement: { [key: string]: number; }, fromIndex?: number) => boolean'.
      Types of parameters 'searchElement' and 'searchElement' are incompatible.
        Type '{ [key: string]: number; }' is not assignable to type 'DSVRowString'.
          Index signatures are incompatible.
            Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

I import d3-ngservice to use d3 object.

```
import { D3Service, D3, Selection } from 'd3-ng2-service';
```

It seems I should rewrite d3.stack().keys line in a typescript format. Any help?

Comment: What is `data`?

Comment: It is in the URL I mentioned. It is in a csv file: https://bl.ocks.org/DimsumPanda/689368252f55179e12185e13c5ed1fee

Comment: If you `console.log(data)` what does it say?

Comment: Please see my edit

Comment: I will have to run `csvParse` to see what I get out of `data`. Can you tell me what `data` is?

Comment: Yes, it is JSON:
[
    {
        "ethnicity": "Asian",
        "F Under 25": "327",
        "F Over 75": "296",
        "F 25 to 50": "332",
        "F 50 to 75": "309",
        "M Under 25": "306",
        "M Over 75": "330",
        "M 25 to 50": "307",
        "M 50 to 75": "323"
    },
    {
        "ethnicity": "Black",
        "F Under 25": "294",
        "F Over 75": "302",
        "F 25 to 50": "330",
        "F 50 to 75": "305",
        "M Under 25": "295",
        "M Over 75": "363",
        "M 25 to 50": "322",
        "M 50 to 75": "292"
    }
]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139402/discussion-between-explosion-pills-and-enayat).