# TypeScript type confusion (TypeError: Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, d3.js

I have the following data in a `csv` file in my Angular project that also imports the `D3.js` library:

```
group,Nitrogen,normal,stress
banana,12,1,13
poacee,6,6,33
sorgho,11,28,12
triticum,19,6,1
```

I also have the following code in the typescript file to display the stacked bar:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as d3 from 'd3';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-stacked-bar',
  templateUrl: './stacked-bar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./stacked-bar.component.css']
})
export class StackedBarComponent implements OnInit {

  data = [
    {"group": "banana", "Nitrogen": "12", "normal": "1", "stress": "13"},
    {"group": "poacee", "Nitrogen": "6", "normal": "6", "stress": "33"},
    {"group": "sorgho", "Nitrogen": "11", "normal": "28", "stress": "12"},
    {"group": "triticum", "Nitrogen": "19", "normal": "6", "stress": "1"}
  ];

  svg: any;

  margin = 50;
  width = 750 - (this.margin * 2);
  height = 400 - (this.margin * 2);

  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.createSvg();
    this.drawBars(this.data);
  }

  createSvg(): void {

    this.svg = d3.select("figure#stacked-bar")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", this.width + (this.margin * 2))
    .attr("height", this.height + (this.margin * 2))
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + this.margin + "," + this.margin + ")");
  }

  drawBars(data): void {
 
    // List of subgroups - Header of the csv file.
    // ["Nitrogen", "normal", "stress"]
    const subgroups = data.columns.slice(1);
            
    // List of groups - Value of the first column, called group.
    const groups = data.map(d => (d.group));

    // Create the X-axis band scale.
    const x = d3.scaleBand()
    .domain(groups)
    .range([0, this.width])
    //.domain(data.map(d => d.groups))
    .padding(0.2);

    // Draw the X-axis on the DOM.
    this.svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + this.height + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x).tickSizeOuter(0));
    
    // Create the Y-axis band scale.
    const y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, 60])
    .range([this.height, 0]);

    // Draw the Y-axis on the DOM.
    this.svg.append("g")
    .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

    // color palette = one color per subgroup
    const color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
    .domain(subgroups)
    .range(['#e41a1c','#377eb8','#4daf4a']);

    // Stack the data per subgroup.
    const stackedData = d3.stack()
    .keys(subgroups)
    (data);

    // Create and fill the bars.
    this.svg.append("g")
    .selectAll("g")
    .data(stackedData)
    .join("g")
    .attr("fill", d => color(d.key))
    .selectAll("rect")    
    .data(d => d)
    .join("rect")
    .attr("x", d => x(d.data.group))
    .attr("y", d => y(d[1]))
    .attr("height", d => y(d[0]) - y(d[1]))
    .attr("width", x.bandwidth());
  }
}
```

But I only get an empty plot. When I inspect the page, I have this console error:

**TypeError: Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined**

Due to some type ambiguity in `data`, the `slice` method cannot be applied, but when I just copy and paste `["Nitrogen", "normal", "stress"]` in place of `subgroups` in code, it all works fine!

Can somebody please help me with this?

p.s. This is how the chart should look like:

[image]

Comment: If it's a runtime error, it doesn't have to do with TypeScript types. TypeScript types are a compilation-time concept (other than enums, which have a runtime presence as values).

Comment: Can you see the cause for this runtime error? In all the examples I have seen, `d => y(d[0]) - y(d[1])` returns a number and it just works. Here, it does not return a number...

Comment: For `.attr("x"...` you use `d` as an object; but for `.attr("height"...` you use `d` as an array. Do you need to refer to a property of `d` when setting `y` and `height` ?

Comment: @Robin Mackenzie I think the anonymous function (using d) basically subtracts the height of each bar recursively, hence an array. I edited my question and added an image of how the stackedbar chart should look like. You can see that, for example, for banana, we need to have a bar with the length of 12 (red) and 1 (blue) and 13 (green). Please see the new image in my post. I hope you can see the problem...

Comment: @CatarinaRuna - Sadly, I can't, but that's not terribly surprising as I don't do Angular and I haven't used `d3`. :-D I'd change that concise arrow function to `d => { /*newline*/ const v1 = y(d[0]), v2 = y(d[1]), retVal = v1 - v2; /*newline*/ return retVal; /*newline*/}`, put a breakpoint on the `return`, and look at the values of `v1`, `v2`, and `retVal`.

Comment: I think I have a hunch! I am trying to remove the header row. Initially, I had `data.column.slice(1)` to drop the header row, but then I removed `column` because I though `data` does not have such a property. Now that I use `console.log` to see the groups and subgroups, I see that the header is not axed, but the first row of my data. How do I simply remove the header line: `group,Nitrogen,normal,stress`?

Comment: What d3 version are you using?

Comment: Please see my new edits. It's not to do with D3. The `slice` method cannot be applied for some reason, but when I just copy and paste `["Nitrogen", "normal", "stress"]` in place of `subgroups` in code, it all works fine. How can I get this `subgroups` array from my `data`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are working from this [example](https://www.d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/barplot_stacked_basicWide.html), then note that this uses `d3.csv` to convert csv input to an array of objects. D3 creates this array *plus* a custom `columns` property that is used in the example.

```js
const csv = `group,Nitrogen,normal,stress
banana,12,1,13
poacee,6,6,33
sorgho,11,28,12
triticum,19,6,1`;

const data = d3.csvParse(csv);
console.log(data.columns);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

In your code, you have the same array of objects, but you don't show the csv import method so we may assume you are not using `d3.csv` and using some other method to get the data.

In this case, the equivalent to `data.columns` is `Object.keys(data[0])`. From there you can use `slice` to get the columns by which you want to group for the stack:

```js
const data = [
  {"group": "banana", "Nitrogen": "12", "normal": "1", "stress": "13"},
  {"group": "poacee", "Nitrogen": "6", "normal": "6", "stress": "33"},
  {"group": "sorgho", "Nitrogen": "11", "normal": "28", "stress": "12"},
  {"group": "triticum", "Nitrogen": "19", "normal": "6", "stress": "1"}
];

const dataColumns = Object.keys(data[0]);
console.log(dataColumns);

const subgroups = dataColumns.slice(1)
console.log(subgroups);
```

Comment: Bless you! That was what I was hoping to find out. It is resolved now. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Can you please try below code?

```
 const subgroups = data.columns?.slice(1) || [];
```

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't work... The `slice` method cannot be applied for some reason, but when I copy and paste `["Nitrogen", "normal", "stress"]` in place of `subgroups` in code, it all works fine. How can I extract this `subgroups` array from my `data`?

Comment: The data doesn't contains subgroups in your code snipped.

data = [
    {"group": "banana", "Nitrogen": "12", "normal": "1", "stress": "13"},
    {"group": "poacee", "Nitrogen": "6", "normal": "6", "stress": "33"},
    {"group": "sorgho", "Nitrogen": "11", "normal": "28", "stress": "12"},
    {"group": "triticum", "Nitrogen": "19", "normal": "6", "stress": "1"}
  ];

Comment: Can you please tell me the requirement to subgroup value?

Comment: let allKeysForIndex0 = Object.keys(data[0]).splice(0);
allKeysForIndex0.splice(0,1)

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand of your code there is no property columns in you data object.

You defined data like this at the beginning of the file :

```
data = [
    {"group": "banana", "Nitrogen": "12", "normal": "1", "stress": "13"},
    {"group": "poacee", "Nitrogen": "6", "normal": "6", "stress": "33"},
    {"group": "sorgho", "Nitrogen": "11", "normal": "28", "stress": "12"},
    {"group": "triticum", "Nitrogen": "19", "normal": "6", "stress": "1"}
  ];
```

So I don't see any property columns.

And data is already an array so I think you should just do :

`const subgroups = data.slice(1)`

And, by the way, you seems to do it correctly for the `groups` variable.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, it does it correctly for the `groups` variable, but for the `subgroups` it drops the first object which is not what I want; I need to drop the header row `group,Nitrogen,normal,stress`

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the possibility to test this myself right now, but what I learned from my coding in TypeScript a lot of similar problems were solved by setting the type of the variable in question to 'any' like this:

```
const subgroups = (data as any).columns.slice(1)
```

Please take this with a grain of salt since my excursion into web programming was short, so I can't say if this method could negatively impact the overall code in some way. Comments on this question are welcome.